# Delete vector of strings from list in R

Tags: r, string, list, vector

I have a list, where each element is vector of strings, of variable length
e.g.,

```
reqr:
chr[1:3] "sales" "communication" "leadership"
chr[1:2] "IT" "customer service"
chr[1:4] "team player" "CSS" "html" "english"
```

I have a vector, `A = c("IT", "CSS", "english")`

I want to remove strings from the list which appear in vector A, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

Set operations are good...

```
lapply(reqr, setdiff, y=A)
#[[1]]
#[1] "sales"         "communication" "leadership"   
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "customer service"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "team player" "html"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lapply` along with `match`

```
lapply(reqr, function(x) x[is.na(match(x, A))])


#$a
#[1] "sales"         "communication" "leadership"   

#$b
#[1] "customer service"

#$c
#[1] "team player" "html"
```